# Android Chronometer disappears when started?

Tags: android

The Chronometer widget initial text is 00:00

but when I start the Chronometer its text becomes blank

How can I display the text of the Chronometer as it counts up ?

Comment: @Ikke: no, it's not. The chronometer widget is something used in code. @Mina: please show us your xml and/or code. It shouldn't disappear like that so you must have done something wrong.

Comment: @Steve H Ok, thought it was just an android desktop widget

Comment: Hi guys
its just a chronometer widget and I have a button that when I click i start the chronometer
note: I didn't set the format of the chronometer, could this be the reason

Comment: You shouldn't need to set a format. It defaults to haveing a dark background, white text and about 10px high text. You need to show us how you've actually implemented this because by your description you haven't done anything wrong, but we'll probably be able to see the fault if we see your code and XML. Alternatively, you can have a look at this question where I went into detail explaining to someone how to make a custom chronometer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536882/create-an-incrementing-timer-in-seconds-in-0000-format/2537264#2537264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys

thanks for your help

I didn't implement the `setOnChronometerTickListener` listner and didn't handle the

```
onChronometerTick
```

method to display the current value of the ChronoMeter

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do those - assuming you are talking about the example I posted, that's only if you want to do something complicated with the Chrono widget. Normally just a simple <Chronometer ...> in your XML followed by a `Chronometer chrono = (Chronometer) findViewBy...` and `chrono.start()` in your code is all you need.

Comment: Thanks steve
what I wanted to do is to make the Chronometer text updates as time elapses