# How to Display the time elapsed onto UI Screen of the Android

Tags: android, user-interface, time, timer

I am writing a app for which i need to display the Time elapsed when user presses a button in UI screen . 
So please guide me in writing the code in Android. I need to display the time in seconds, mins and hours.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: There's a demo/discussion of this [on the android dev blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current system time in milliseconds by calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`. You can store this in an variable on Activity start and then calculate the difference between the current time and the stored time in the `onClick` method of the button.

example:

```
class ExampleApp exnteds Activity {
    private long startTime;
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ...

    public void onMyButtonClick(View v) {
        long timeGoneMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        long timeGoneSecs = timeGoneMillis / 1000;
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the heads up ! i also found solution for similar problem, so wanted share the URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536882?tab=newest#tab-top