# Android Intent action/receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm working on an android application.

I have a chronometer (timer) that is started by clicking a button.

What I want is a toast to be displayed every hour saying an hour has passed (or every minute for testing).

I understand that I need to use a combination of intents, recievers and broadcast recievers however I'm stuck on what code to use.

Can somebody please help me with the code to perform the function required?

Comment: Either of the options below will work, however; for your chronometer, if its necessary, you should go with SatishBabu's claim.. problem is if your Activity leaves, the chronometer won't be running if its in the Activity.

Comment: thanks for the replies. Can anybody provide a code example, I'm relatively new to android and Java?

Comment: Just google it.. ChronoMeter Example.. you'll find a ton of them. Dont be so scared to venture out and search for things on your own. This is how learning takes place.

Comment: I have done, struggled to find anything where actions are performed at intervals

Answer (score 1):

Use setOnChronometerTickListener (Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener listener)

refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setOnChronometerTickListener(android.widget.Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener)

Answer (score 0):

Just Start an alarm using an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) that will send an intent to a service that will display a Toast.

**Update**

[Create an incrementing timer in seconds in 00:00 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536882/create-an-incrementing-timer-in-seconds-in-0000-format)

I'd recommend trying both options to see which you like better.