# Why isn't onChronometerTick being called?

Tags: android, chronometer

My code never enters the onChronometerTick method. What am I doing incorrectly? Do I need to set the tick time somehow? I can't figure out a way to do that.

```
elapsedTimer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        countUp[0] = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000;
        elapsedTimeDynamic.setText("" + countUp);
    }
});
elapsedTimer.start();
```

Comment: Did you try starting it before listener?

Comment: yes, that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone in the future who is having trouble using chronometer for an elapsed timer/stopwatch and can't figure it out, I ended up scrapping chronometer and using CountDownTimer, but using it in such a way that it would also count up:

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
elapsedTimer = new CountDownTimer(activityTime + 1000, 100) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime/1000;
        elapsedTimeTextView.setText(String.format("%02d", (elapsedTime)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: How is this counting up?

Comment: Well my textview appeared to be counting up is what I meant. Because it was showing the elapsedTime variable which was currentTime-startTime.